# What 'expression:' property in QML Item

Tags: qml

I've inherited a collection of mostly undocumented QML code. I'm new to QML, and I'm struggling to understand this code. In particular, the construct

```
expression: "connected == false"
```

occurs frequently in various items, but I can't find any documentation on what this property does. It does not seem to be defined anywhere in the existing code collection, so I'm assuming it's part of QML, but I'm having no luck turning it up anywhere.

It looks as though all items using this construct are backed by C++ classes. However, "expression" is not defined as a QPROPERTY anywhere in the C++ code.

Comment: Can you post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This code isn't complete; we have zero context to go on.

Comment: The code is proprietary, so I'm reluctant to post it. But it's basically no more than Item{...expression: "connected == false"...} with a handful of other, standard properties along with some defined in the underlying c++ class. All I'm wondering is if the 'expression' property is a part of standard QML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there's no such property in QML. You'll have to look into the QML file for the type that it's used in, or the C++ if it's declared there.